# updating a record based on parent id

Tags: database, t-sql

i have a table

```
intProductID    vchProductName  intParentCategory   intCategoryId
1                     Post Cards       NULL                      3
2                     Packaging Boxe   NULL                       5
3                  12- Page Booklets   1                         NULL
4                  16- Page Booklets   12                        NULL
```

i want to update intcategory id of which rows which have intcategory id is null also i want to  update  intCategoryId with a value which its parent (intParentCategory) have.

for example intproductid 3 have intparentid 1 so i want intcategoryid 3 for intproductid 3 which its parent have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update t1
set intcategoryID = t2.intCategoryId
from <table> t1
join <table> t2
on t1.intParentCategory = t2.intProductID
where t1.intCategoryId is null
```

Here is a solution with test table that will update the entire tree for parent hierarchies

```
declare @t table(intProductID int, vchProductName varchar(20),  intParentCategory int,  intCategoryId int)

insert @t values(1, 'Post Cards',NULL,3),
(2,'Packaging Boxe',   NULL,5),
(3,'12- Page Booklets',   1,NULL),
(4,'16- Page Booklets',12, NULL),
(5,'tst', 3, null)
--select intCategoryId, intProductID
--from @t where intCategoryId is not null and intProductID is not null

;with cte as
(
select intCategoryId, intProductID
from @t where intCategoryId is not null and intProductID is not null
union all
select cte.intCategoryId, t.intProductID
from @t t 
join cte
on t.intParentCategory = cte.intProductID
and t.intCategoryId is null
)
update t
set t.intCategoryId = cte.intCategoryId
from @t t
join cte
on t.intProductID = cte.intProductID
option (maxrecursion 5000)

select * from @t
```

Comment: no its not like that
i want to update intcategoryid with values of intcategoryid which its parent have... geting my poiint??

Comment: @MuhammadJawad isn't that exactly what I did ? If not please make change your post to include expected data

Comment: intcategoryID of parent will become the intcaregoryid for child. i want to update accordingly

Comment: @MuhammadJawad I gave it another try

Comment: Unfortunately, this proposition would not update the entire tree for parent hierarchies.

Comment: @GerardoLima which i would have included it it was described in the question. This could also result in an endless loop

Comment: i assumed a tree not a graph would represent this hierarchy; nevertheless, the loop would be very easy to solve by adding a "not-in-already-updated-records" check ...

Comment: @GerardoLima your tree has been included

Comment: @t-clausen.dk 
Thanks buddy for the answer, it works for my case... :)